# How can I use my custom redirect URI to authorise?

Tags: swift, xcode, oauth

I am trying to make a very basic app that uses the Home Assistant OAuth2 API to authorise. I am trying to use a simple ASWebAuthenticationSession and have gotten that all working. The only problem is that I get an error that I have an incorrect redirect uri. I think this is because I am using a custom URL type setup with my app. In the Home Assistant docs they say that we can get around this by adding something like this [`<link rel='redirect_uri' href='customredirecturi://auth'>`](https://developers.home-assistant.io/docs/en/auth_api.html) to enable our custom redirect uri's to work. How would I go about adding this to my app so that it works? Sorry if it's a dumb question, I'm still getting my head around all the OAuth stuff.

Thanks!